# Find the adherence values of $z_n=1+\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I know that the definition of a limit point is the set of all points $z$ such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|z_n-z|<\varepsilon$, but I do not understand how to go about finding the limit point(s) $z$.  I believe that $2$ and $1$ are the limit points based on the initial values of the sequence but how do I go about showing that? Thanks!

Comment: The definition of $\;z\;$ isn't clear. Use MathJaX

Comment: @DonAntonio z is a point in the complex plane, and n=1,2,.....

Comment: As far as I can see/guess, $\;z\in\Bbb R\;$ ...but what is that * in the definition of $\;z\;$? Did you actually mean $$z=1+(-1)^n\frac n{n+1}=1+\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}\;?$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, my apologies. I'm getting used to the language. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $z_n\in\mathbb{R}$ hence $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, 0\leqslant z_n\leqslant 2 $$
so that $z\in[0,2]$. On the other hand $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{z_{2n}}=2$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{z_{2n+1}}=0$ and, since $$z_{n+1}-z_n=(-1)^n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}\longrightarrow 0$$
the set of the adherence values of $(z_n)$ is an interval, hence it is $[0,2]$.

Proof of the lemma : if $(u_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded and such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(u_{n+1}-u_n)=0$ then the set of the adherence values of $(u_n)$ $\mathcal{A}$ is an interval.

According to Bolzano-Weierstrass's theorem, $\mathcal{A}\neq\emptyset$, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a singleton, then it's done. Let us suppose that there exists $(\ell_1<\ell_2)\in\mathcal{A}^2$ and let $\ell\in]\ell_1,\ell_2[$, we will show that $\ell\in\mathcal{A}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$, according to the definition of the limit :
$$ \exists n_0\geqslant N,\forall n\geqslant n_0,\,|u_{n+1}-u_n|<\varepsilon $$
$$ \exists n_1\geqslant n_0,\forall n\geqslant n_1,\,u_n<\ell \text{ (because } \ell_1 \text{ is an adherence value)} $$
$$ \exists n_2\geqslant n_1,\forall n\geqslant n_2,\,u_n>\ell \text{ (because } \ell_2 \text{ is an adherence value)} $$
Let $p=\max\{ n\in[\![n_1,n_2]\!]\ |\ u_n<\ell \}$, you have
$$ u_p<\ell\leqslant u_{p+1} $$ so that $0<\ell-u_p\leqslant u_{p+1}-u_p <\varepsilon$, hence $\ell\in\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is an interval.

Comment: can you explain why you took the limits of the two subsequences and how that shows the interval of adherence values is [0,2]? I'm still a bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: Let us assume that the set of the adherence values $\mathcal{A}$ is an interval, we first prove that $[0,2]\subset\mathcal{A}$. By showing that $0,2\in\mathcal{A}$, since $\mathcal{A}$ is an interval you have $\mathcal{A}\subset[0,2]$ so that $\mathcal{A}=[0,2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would this same method extend to complex sequences? The next part of the question asks me to do this for z= $\frac{1}{m}$ + $\frac{i}{n}$ (m, n= ±1,±2,....)

Comment: There it doesn't apply since there are $2$ variables. The adherence of $\{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{i}{n}\ |\ (m,n)\in(\mathbb{Z}^*)^2\}$ is kind of itself but you have to add some zeros.